# How to display the value of a ulong in the text property of a label in c# forms .net?

Tags: c#

How to display the value of a ulong in the text property of a label in c#? I'm really new to c# sorry if that's a dumb question.

(this is in an "if" that works apart from this)

```
label1.Text = nameOfUlong;
```

I didn't know that you can't convert ulong to string I guess.

Comment: there's an easy way to convert a ulong to it's string representation: `nameOfUlong.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *string interpolation*:

```
label1.Text = $"{nameOfUlong}";
```

it is especially convenient when you want to put value somewhere in the middle of the string:

```
label1.Text = $"My value ({nameOfUlong}) is ulong";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```cs
label1.Text = nameOfUlong.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, there are several simple ways to get the string representation of an ulong type (and many others)

```
ulong myUlong = 12;

// ToString() conversion
label1.Text = myUlong.ToString();

// string concatenation (implicit ToString())
label1.Text = myUlong + "";

// string interpolation
label1.Text = $"{myUlong}";

// string format
label1.Text = string.Format("{0}", myUlong);

// System.Convert
label1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(myUlong);
```